# PIN screen and PIN have changed on Huawei P8 Lite with Android 7

Tags: lock-screens

When I accessed my phone yesterday, the PIN screen had changed (presumably through an automatic software update). I put in my pin and it didn't recognize it.  I have not changed my pin. Luckily, I have fingerprint control set up so I can use my phone.  My worry is that sometimes the fingerprint recognition doesn't work. If this happens, I have lost my phone!

I have searched for info on the PIN changing by itself but Android/Huawei are not admitting to this happening. It is suspicious that the PIN screen has changed at the same time as the PIN changed. Does anyone have any information on this please?

Comment: If you have activated "Google Find My Device" as device administrator on the device you can remotely change your PIN using the Google Find My Device web site.

Comment: Hi Robert.  I guess I didn't set find my device up on the phone as I have tried to find it and it can't be found.  I'll give it another go but I am not holding out any hope.

Answer (score 1):

PIN does not change automatically. And to remove pin, you need old pin.

You are able to access phone. So first take backup of the phone and restore phone. This will remove pin from phone. After that you can set pin. If you are not able to access phone then you may loss data.

Some application and software can recover lost pin.

Comment: The phone recently started asking me for a Password.  It did not accept my Pin.  I used my fingerprint to access the phone.  I have in the meantime been speaking to Huawei support who think the software may have become corrupted.  I did not set a password as I use a Pin.  I HAVE NOT FORGOTTEN MY PIN - I am just not being given the chance to enter it.  Sadly, as it has now been three days, the phone requires a password or pin and won't !et me access it using fingerprints.  If no-one has any ideas then it looks like a factory reset.  Just please don't keep telling me that I have forgotten my pin

Comment: Google find my device did not find it.

Comment: Find my device can remotely unlock device.

Comment: Hi Alix, I have tried to "find" it but it can't be found so I can't unlock it .  But thanks for the suggestion.  What I really need is a way of making it give me back the pin entry screen instead of this password entry one.  Unless anyone knows if there is a default password.  I've tried the usual like 0000 and 1111 and even "password" in desperation!

Comment: If you forgot pin then PUK can unlock phone. Have you inserted sim inside mobile or not. If sim is not inserted than pin will not be asked.

Comment: Tried the PUK code but it didn't unlock the phone.